# Pandas: filter one dataframe by multiple, simultaneous column values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a filtered dataframe called `correct_df` and a raw dataframe `example_df`.

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': ['Test_1', 'Test_1', 'Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_2', 'Test_2', 'Test_3', 'Test_3', 'Test_3'], 'A': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
other_df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': ['Test_1', 'Test_1', 'Test_3', 'Test_3'], 'A': [1, 2, 1, 3]})
```

Desired result:

I want the indexes of `example_df` where 'Test' and 'A' column values both match the combined row value of `correct_df`.

I have tried:

```
result = example_df.loc[ (example_df['Test'].isin(other_df['Test'])) & (example_df['A'].isin(other_df['A'])) ]
result

    Test    A
0   Test_1  1
1   Test_1  2
2   Test_1  3
6   Test_3  1
7   Test_3  2
8   Test_3  3
```

But as these two conditions are separated, the resulting value only applies the conditions on single columns without chaining them i.e. A then also B, not A and B. How do I get the .loc of both column conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for avoid lost indices and then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
result = example_df.reset_index().merge(other_df, on=['Test','A'])
print (result)
   index    Test  A
0      0  Test_1  1
1      1  Test_1  2
2      6  Test_3  1
3      8  Test_3  3
```

---

```
result = (example_df.reset_index()
                    .merge(other_df, on=['Test','A'])
                    .set_index('index')
                    .rename_axis(None))
print (result)
     Test  A
0  Test_1  1
1  Test_1  2
6  Test_3  1
8  Test_3  3
```

Another idea with `MultiIndex` with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
result = example_df[example_df.set_index(['Test','A']).index
                              .isin(other_df.set_index(['Test','A']).index)]
print (result)
     Test  A
0  Test_1  1
1  Test_1  2
6  Test_3  1
8  Test_3  3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's done the trick. Didn't think to merge. Is there a method that can use .loc[] out of curiosity, or is that beyond the scope of conditional indexing?

Comment: @PeptideWitch - you need filter by both columns together, so `loc` is problematic. Added another solution for filter by `MultiIndex` and `isin` for filter by both columns

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael's solution is absolutely perfect for your question. This is just another way (a little convoluted) to get the same outcome using numpy.

We can filter `example_df` directly using a boolean array which we can construct by checking if rows in `example_df` exist `other_df`. To do that we need to make `example_df` a 3D array and use numpy broadcasting to compare with `other_df`. Then use `all` and `any` to shrink it back to the 1D array `msk`:

```
msk = (example_df.to_numpy()[:, None]==other_df.to_numpy()).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
out = example_df[msk]
```

Output:

```
     Test  A
0  Test_1  1
1  Test_1  2
6  Test_3  1
8  Test_3  3
```

Comment: Thinking why this is not used obviously and in my opinion memory problems if compare in broadcasting in larger DataFrames. In another words `(example_df.to_numpy()[:, None]==other_df.to_numpy())` create huge 3d array.

Comment: @jezrael I agree; if the DataFrames are large, this will very quickly run into memory problems. That’s why I said your solution is best.